# Postman Bulk API 2.0 Delete: Error "The 'delete' batch must contain only ids"

Tags: delete, bulk-delete, postman, bulk-api-v2

trying to test Bulk API delete functionality in Postman desktop. I created a Job like so

```
{
    "object": "et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c",
    "operation": "delete",
    "contentType" : "CSV",
    "lineEnding" : "CRLF"
}
```

And for my Upload data job I do raw text

```
{
    "ID": "a2s1G000005Kzk2QAC"
}
```

After I close my job with "UploadComplete" status and check the job info it tells me:

```
   "errorMessage": "InvalidBatch : InvalidBatch : The 'delete' batch must contain only ids"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to post JSON, but you stated you're posting a CSV. Try this:

```
Id
a2s1G000005Kzk2QAC
```

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked. Follow-up up question. What if I want to have a CSV file with all my IDs to delete. On the Upload data job screen I select "binary" and select csv file.
My file only has one column. First row says: Id (not quotes or anything), and all subsequent rows are a2s1G.... stings.
Now when I close the job the same error.

Comment: @ArtS check out [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_prepare_csv.htm) to make sure your following all the rules, and make sure every Id is exactly right. You may also have the wrong line ending (see above link). In addition, the docs say something about base64 encoding, so I think you may need to do that as well.

Comment: I could not figure out what was wrong with my CSV file, so I solved the issue by opening up Notepad++, entering my IDs and doing save as .csv uft-8.